# App linking verification failed on installation process

Tags: android

I am trying to setup app linking for my app. The app is associated to the website according to the app link assistant, but for some reason the verification process failed on the installation process.

Here is the intent filter for my app

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
      android:host="staging.lemonilo.com"
      android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

the location for my assetlinks.json

```
https://staging.lemonilo.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

error log from the catlog using git bash

```
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815 16129 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier: Verification result: checking for a statement with source a: # brgr@3ede8955
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815 16129 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier: w: 32
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815 16129 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier: , relation delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls, and target b <
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815 16129 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:   a: "com.lemonilo"
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815 16129 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:   b: # brgp@8358a08
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815 16129 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:   w: 113
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815 16129 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier: >
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815 16129 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier: w: 115
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815 16129 I SingleHostAsyncVerifier:  --> false.
08-16 10:34:41.738 15815  9034 I IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification 28 complete. Success:false. Failed hosts:staging.lemonilo.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

first, make sure both http and https scheme provided. even your app only capture the http or only https. you can combine it like this:

```
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="yourbaseurl.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/path"/>
```

secondly, make sure `assetlinks.json` that you export from Android Studio App Link Assistant.

third, especially for playstore deploy version. make sure to add the correct sha256_cert_fingerprints, which is your sha256 cert fingerprint for app signing certificate not your upload certificate (its available on your app release dashboard, Release Management --> App signing)

You can combine multiple sha256 fingerprints in one assetlinks, separate it with comma. for example this one:

https://log.girilabs.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: tried adding http on the intent filter, still not working. Is there any other way to know why the verification process failed?

Comment: have you try fetching the assetlinks file from postman? make sure the content type is `application/json`, make sure to follow guides in here to: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

Comment: I have also struggling on this one, in my cases, there are 2 kind of problem that I found, the first one is the content type is `plain/text` because I am using shared hosting, that automatically changes the content type of json files, the second one is because I put the wrong files, I didn't use the assetslink file that generated using android studio.

Comment: you could check the content type that returned by your server using postman.

Comment: tried fetching from postman, the content type is ```application/json```. Should i make the assetlinks.json accessible through http?